# Android, how to change activity field from LocationListener.onlocationchanged()?

Tags: android

How do I change an activity field from LocationListener.onlocationchanged() ? I suppose I have to use a handler, but don't know how to do it, exactly...
My code is like this:

```
public class Main extends Activity {
    private Double lat, lon;
    private LocationManager locationManager;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        LocationListener locationListenerGps = new CurrentLocationGps();
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListenerGps);
    }
}

public class CurrentLocationGps implements LocationListener {
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
        lat = loc.getLatitude();
        lon = loc.getLongitude();
>>>>>>>>---<<<<<<<<< How do I pass this values to Main activity fields?
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the CurrentLocationGps class inside the Main class (making it an [inner class](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/innerclasses.html)), this way you can access all the fields in Main activity.

Comment: I used it as an  inner class (the code I wrote in the question was wrong...), but didn't know outer class was accessible from the inner one... Thanks! ;-(